# Get descendants from specific XML element using LINQ to XML Query

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

This is my XML

```
<xml time="1459844720">
<Competitions>
<Competition name="1. Bundesliga" id="GER_1" season="2015/2016" country="Germany" country_id="GER"/>
<Competition name="Allsvenskan" id="SWE_1" season="2016" country="Sweden" country_id="SWE"/>
<Competition name="Belgian Pro League" id="BEL_1" season="2015/2016" country="Belgium" country_id="BEL"/>
<Competition name="Championship" id="ENG_2" season="2015/2016" country="England" country_id="ENG">
<Matches>...</Matches>
</Competition>
<Competition name="Copa del Rey" id="ESP_C_1" season="2015/2016" country="Spain" country_id="ESP"/>
<Competition name="Coppa Italia" id="ITA_C_1" season="2015/2016" country="Italy" country_id="ITA"/>
<Competition name="Coupe de France" id="FRA_C_1" season="2015/2016" country="France" country_id="FRA"/>
<Competition name="DFB Pokal" id="GER_C_1" season="2015/2016" country="Germany" country_id="GER"/>
<Competition name="Eredivisie" id="NED_1" season="2015/2016" country="Netherlands" country_id="NED"/>
<Competition name="European Championship" id="INT_5" season="2016" country="International" country_id="INT"/>
<Competition name="FA Cup" id="ENG_C_1" season="2015/2016" country="England" country_id="ENG"/>
<Competition name="League of Ireland" id="IRL_1" season="2016" country="Ireland" country_id="IRL"/>
<Competition name="Liga MX" id="MEX_1" season="2016" country="Mexico" country_id="MEX"/>
<Competition name="Ligue 1" id="FRA_1" season="2015/2016" country="France" country_id="FRA"/>
<Competition name="Major League Soccer" id="USA_1" season="2016" country="USA" country_id="USA"/>
<Competition name="Premier League" id="ENG_1" season="2015/2016" country="England" country_id="ENG"/>
<Competition name="Premiership" id="SCO_1" season="2015/2016" country="Scotland" country_id="SCO">...</Competition>
<Competition name="Primeira Liga" id="POR_1" season="2015/2016" country="Portugal" country_id="POR"/>
<Competition name="Primera Division" id="ESP_1" season="2015/2016" country="Spain" country_id="ESP"/>
<Competition name="Russia Premier League" id="RUS_1" season="2015/2016" country="Russia" country_id="RUS"/>
<Competition name="Serie A" id="ITA_1" season="2015/2016" country="Italy" country_id="ITA"/>
<Competition name="Süper Lig" id="TUR_1" season="2015/2016" country="Turkey" country_id="TUR"/>
<Competition name="Superligaen" id="DEN_1" season="2015/2016" country="Denmark" country_id="DEN"/>
<Competition name="Tippeligaen" id="NOR_1" season="2016" country="Norway" country_id="NOR"/>
<Competition name="UEFA Champions League" id="INT_3" season="2015/2016" country="International" country_id="INT">
<Matches>
<Match match_id="195b0cfda1cc7e16c762699080a2954a" match_name="Bayern Munich-Benfica" match_date="2016-04-05 20:45:00" match_status="notstarted" home_id="BAYERN-MUNICH" home_name="Bayern Munich" away_id="BENFICA" away_name="Benfica"/>
<Match match_id="e513150fea7879711ddefd18c7cd78a9" match_name="Barcelona-Atletico Madrid" match_date="2016-04-05 20:45:00" match_status="notstarted" home_id="BARCELONA" home_name="Barcelona" away_id="ATLETICO-MADRID" away_name="Atletico Madrid"/>
</Matches>
</Competition>
<Competition name="UEFA Europa League" id="INT_23" season="2015/2016" country="International" country_id="INT"/>
</Competitions>
</xml>
```

I want to get All the competition name and the match name. The result will be like this :

- Championship
  Reading-Nottingham Forest
  Birmingham-Brighton
  Brentford-Bolton
  Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
  Bristol City-Rotherham
  Ipswich-Charlton
  Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
  Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
  Preston-Fulham
- FA Cup
- Premier League

This is my code

```
Sub GetData()
        Dim doc = XDocument.Load("E:\Web Project\Bootstrap\Score\Score\fixtures.xml")
        Dim compCountry As String = "England"
        Dim compQuery = From competition In doc.Descendants.Elements("Competition")
                   Select New With {
                        .Name = competition.Attribute("name").Value,
                        .Country = competition.Attribute("country").Value,
                        .Child = competition.Descendants("Match").Value
                    }


        Dim comp = compQuery.First
        Dim comps = compQuery.ToList

        Dim sTable


        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        For i = 0 To comps.Count - 1

            sTable = comps(i).Name & " - " & comps(i).Country
            lblTest.Text = lblTest.Text & sTable & "<br>"
            Dim mQuery = From x In doc.Descendants("Match")
                         Select New With {
                             .Match = x.Attribute("match_name").Value
                         }

            Dim mRes = mQuery.ToList
            For j = 0 To mRes.Count - 1
                Dim sMatch As String = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" & mRes(j).Match
                lblTest.Text = lblTest.Text & sMatch & "<br>"
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

But this is what I got from the code above

```
1. Bundesliga - Germany
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Allsvenskan - Sweden
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Belgian Pro League - Belgium
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Championship - England
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Copa del Rey - Spain
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Coppa Italia - Italy
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Coupe de France - France
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
DFB Pokal - Germany
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Eredivisie - Netherlands
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
European Championship - International
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
FA Cup - England
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
League of Ireland - Ireland
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Liga MX - Mexico
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Ligue 1 - France
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Major League Soccer - USA
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Premier League - England
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Premiership - Scotland
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Primeira Liga - Portugal
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Primera Division - Spain
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Russia Premier League - Russia
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Serie A - Italy
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Süper Lig - Turkey
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Superligaen - Denmark
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
Tippeligaen - Norway
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
UEFA Champions League - International
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
UEFA Europa League - International
   Reading-Nottingham Forest
   Birmingham-Brighton
   Brentford-Bolton
   Leeds-Queens Park Rangers
   Bristol City-Rotherham
   Ipswich-Charlton
   Middlesbrough-Huddersfield
   Milton Keynes Dons-Wolverhampton Wanderers
   Preston-Fulham
   Sheffield Wednesday-Blackburn
   Derby-Hull
   Burnley-Cardiff
   Partick T.-Dundee U.
   Dundee FC-Celtic
   Bayern Munich-Benfica
   Barcelona-Atletico Madrid
```

Can anyone help find a solution for this?

Comment: You have assigned compCountry and then never used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are not provided the complete XML file. The below sample is prepared on the basis of what you mentioned in the description. You may try this in the following way:

```
Public Sub test00()
        Dim frag As XElement = <xml time="1459844720">
                                   <Competitions>
                                       <Competition name="1. Bundesliga" id="GER_1" season="2015/2016" country="Germany" country_id="GER"/>
                                       <Competition name="Allsvenskan" id="SWE_1" season="2016" country="Sweden" country_id="SWE"/>
                                       <Competition name="Belgian Pro League" id="BEL_1" season="2015/2016" country="Belgium" country_id="BEL"/>
                                       <Competition name="Championship" id="ENG_2" season="2015/2016" country="England" country_id="ENG">
                                           <Matches>...</Matches>
                                       </Competition>
                                       <Competition name="Copa del Rey" id="ESP_C_1" season="2015/2016" country="Spain" country_id="ESP"/>
                                       <Competition name="Coppa Italia" id="ITA_C_1" season="2015/2016" country="Italy" country_id="ITA"/>
                                       <Competition name="Coupe de France" id="FRA_C_1" season="2015/2016" country="France" country_id="FRA"/>
                                       <Competition name="DFB Pokal" id="GER_C_1" season="2015/2016" country="Germany" country_id="GER"/>
                                       <Competition name="Eredivisie" id="NED_1" season="2015/2016" country="Netherlands" country_id="NED"/>
                                       <Competition name="European Championship" id="INT_5" season="2016" country="International" country_id="INT"/>
                                       <Competition name="FA Cup" id="ENG_C_1" season="2015/2016" country="England" country_id="ENG"/>
                                       <Competition name="League of Ireland" id="IRL_1" season="2016" country="Ireland" country_id="IRL"/>
                                       <Competition name="Liga MX" id="MEX_1" season="2016" country="Mexico" country_id="MEX"/>
                                       <Competition name="Ligue 1" id="FRA_1" season="2015/2016" country="France" country_id="FRA"/>
                                       <Competition name="Major League Soccer" id="USA_1" season="2016" country="USA" country_id="USA"/>
                                       <Competition name="Premier League" id="ENG_1" season="2015/2016" country="England" country_id="ENG"/>
                                       <Competition name="Premiership" id="SCO_1" season="2015/2016" country="Scotland" country_id="SCO">...</Competition>
                                       <Competition name="Primeira Liga" id="POR_1" season="2015/2016" country="Portugal" country_id="POR"/>
                                       <Competition name="Primera Division" id="ESP_1" season="2015/2016" country="Spain" country_id="ESP"/>
                                       <Competition name="Russia Premier League" id="RUS_1" season="2015/2016" country="Russia" country_id="RUS"/>
                                       <Competition name="Serie A" id="ITA_1" season="2015/2016" country="Italy" country_id="ITA"/>
                                       <Competition name="Süper Lig" id="TUR_1" season="2015/2016" country="Turkey" country_id="TUR"/>
                                       <Competition name="Superligaen" id="DEN_1" season="2015/2016" country="Denmark" country_id="DEN"/>
                                       <Competition name="Tippeligaen" id="NOR_1" season="2016" country="Norway" country_id="NOR"/>
                                       <Competition name="UEFA Champions League" id="INT_3" season="2015/2016" country="International" country_id="INT">
                                           <Matches>
                                               <Match match_id="195b0cfda1cc7e16c762699080a2954a" match_name="Bayern Munich-Benfica" match_date="2016-04-05 20:45:00" match_status="notstarted" home_id="BAYERN-MUNICH" home_name="Bayern Munich" away_id="BENFICA" away_name="Benfica"/>
                                               <Match match_id="e513150fea7879711ddefd18c7cd78a9" match_name="Barcelona-Atletico Madrid" match_date="2016-04-05 20:45:00" match_status="notstarted" home_id="BARCELONA" home_name="Barcelona" away_id="ATLETICO-MADRID" away_name="Atletico Madrid"/>
                                           </Matches>
                                       </Competition>
                                       <Competition name="UEFA Europa League" id="INT_23" season="2015/2016" country="International" country_id="INT"/>
                                   </Competitions>
                               </xml>
        Dim q1 = frag...<Competition>.Select(Function(c) c.@name).Distinct
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For Each cn$ In q1
            sb.AppendLine("• " & cn)
            Dim q2 = frag...<Match>.Where(Function(c) c.Parent.Parent.@name = cn)
            If q2.Count > 0 Then
                For Each ele0 As XElement In q2
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} — {1}", ele0.Parent.Parent.@country, ele0.@match_name))
                Next ele0
            End If
        Next cn
        MsgBox(sb.ToString)
    End Sub
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks @Cylian ! your code works. But what if I want to filter the country. for example, I want to show Competition where country="England". How to put this ?

Comment: @Robert: Then just get a distinct list of countries...and iterate over the same way in the next round...